# Error while executing lsof from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to check for the process which are running on a particular port and if present kill them, as i have to start another process on that port.

Below is my code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TEST_CASE_PATH="$HOME/Projects";

#kill Previous Process Running on port 9130

OUTPUT="$(ls -1)"
echo "${OUTPUT}" # Getting proper Output

PORT_NUMBER=9130
IS_RUNNING = "$(lsof -i tcp:${PORT_NUMBER} |  awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill)"

echo "${IS_RUNNING}" # this fails
```

The $OUTPUT seems to work perfectly, but the piped command seems to break.

And am getting error like :

> IS_RUNNING: command not found

Anybody knows how to fix this one.

Thanks

Comment: i had a similar issue and trying your code i am getting an error : `kill not enough arguments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have additional spaces at the declaration of IS_RUNNING. Try

```
IS_RUNNING="$(lsof...)"
```